# Mysql fulltext search sort

Tags: mysql, sorting

If I search like `AGAINST ('word1 word2 word3' IN BOOLEAN MODE)` how can I have the results to be sorted but the number of words found?

For example:

> row1 - all words
>   2. row2 - word1 and word2
>   3. row3 - word1 and word3
>   4. row4 - word3

... etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume that word is everything  that delimited by spaces you can order by the following (it's amount of words):

```
`length(text) - length(replace(text, ' ', ''))
```

You can do it more elaborate if you want skip single chars such as `-`, `?`.

The final algorithm depends what we count as "word" and what we didn't/

Comment: i had the same problem i tried to do this solution but not clear how to do this, please see my question here 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27264834/mysql-search-sort-with-relavency-with-boolean-mode